# New Xcode 10 Generating dsym File issue

Tags: xcode10, dsym

In Xcode 9 it's working perfectly and Xcode 10 my mac is hanging when generating dSYM file.

I am using MobileVLCKit for playing Live Radio Streaming URL and when I removed MobileVLCKit then it's work in Xcode 10 also.

Anyone help me out from this things.
In New Xcode 10 When I am Archive build of my Xcode Project for the production purpose at that time Xcode is hanging and my mac is also hanging and stuck at the generating dsym file.

Please see the screenshot for my Debug Information Formate settings.

[image]

Comment: Did you find anything about the problem? I've noticed that dsym fiels are not being upload to fabric either because of XCode 10.

Comment: @mkeremkeskin sorry brother but till now i am not found the solution.

Answer (score 1):

There is only some workarounds:

1. build your product without dSYM
2. You can drop the Xcode10.1
   iPhoneOS.sdk folders into Xcode 9.4's folders
   /Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/
   and
   /Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/
   , rename them respectively and archive with symbols and 12.1
   support.

Workaround was mentioned in https://code.videolan.org/videolan/VLCKit/issues/202

Answer (score 1):

A workaround is to copy the file `dsymutil` in Xcode 9 to `dsymutil` in Xcode 10. I found the file located here: `/usr/bin/dsymutil`

This workaround was mentioned in the Apple Developer Forum, but does not mention where to find the file.

Found here: https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/107570

Answer (score 1):

In project go to `Build Settings` and search for `Debug Information format` and change the format to `DWARF`. it will solve the issue.

Comment: While this is not an answer, Please use comment section. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Fixed for me!

Answer (score 0):

We resolved this by removing optimizations for Swift Compile in the build settings:

Build Settings -> Swift Compiler - Code Generation -> Release

set to "No Optimizations"

Original fix suggested by JacobJ84 on Apple forum: https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/115185

Comment: This shouldn't be the solution as sometimes optimizations are wanted